# Allowing a widget to overlay another widget

Tags: flutter

I was trying to achieve an effect of allowing a widget to overlay to another widget
 as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YR70s.png)

The code I've this far is this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return new Column(children: <Widget>[
      new Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      height: screenSize.height / 2,
      width: screenSize.width,
      child: new Center(
        child: new Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 320.0),
          color: Colors.red,
          height: 40.0,
          width: 40.0,
        ),
      ))
]);
}
```

This resulted in the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJpOn.png), the square is cut off by the container.
Is there another approach to this?

Comment: I guess https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html is what you're looking for

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally speaking you should *never* overflow in flutter.

If you want a specific layout, you'll need to explicitly separate the "overflowing" widget on a different layer.

One solution for that is [`Stack`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) widget, which allow widgets to be above each others.

In the end to achieve this :

[image]

the flutter code would be

```
new Stack(
  fit: StackFit.expand,
  children: <Widget>[
    new Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Expanded(
          child: new Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ),
        new Expanded(
          child: new Container(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    new Center(
      child: new Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        height: 40.0,
        width: 40.0,
      ),
    )
  ],
);
```

Comment: is there any way to take the container at the bottom of the screen? I tried `alignment` but seems like I may have to increase the height of the `Container` to see that in effect.

Comment: I don't get what you want. Can you make a question about it? I would gladly answer it

Comment: IMO, it's just a small thing, a comment can do the work. Anyways, let me clarify that, in the screenshot above, we can see the red colored `Container` is in the middle of the screen, how can we align that particular container to be present at the center-bottom of the screen (that means in the center-bottom of the white container which is 2nd container of the `Column`)

Comment: Replace the Center by Align with `alignment` as `Alignment.bottomCenter`. You can also remove the Center entirely and set alignment on Stack directly

Comment: Also have a look at LayoutBuilder. If you have complicated layouts that you want to layout according to the current size, LayoutBuilder plus Stack is quite handy.

Comment: In my case it is just an animation. It only overflows for a couple of milliseconds, but still gives the error.