# Allow widget to overflow

Tags: flutter

I would like to create my own safe area view but instead of just cutting off the overflown area, I would like to have the overflowing area blocked by a semi transparent background.

I realise this question is somewhat similar to [Allowing a widget to overflow to another widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49049546/allowing-a-widget-to-overflow-to-another-widget) but the answer there can solve that question in particular but not mine.

So how do I make the flutter widget overflow?

I used stack to place a container above the view when there's a top overflow and below if there's a bottom overflow. The result works good except that its overflowing to the semi transparent background.

[image: screenshot]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Didian',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: OpacitySafeArea(
          child: RandomWords()
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OpacitySafeArea extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  OpacitySafeArea({
    @required this.child
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var deviceData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    var height = deviceData.size.height;
    var width = deviceData.size.width;
    var top = deviceData.padding.top;
    var bottom = deviceData.padding.bottom;
    print(deviceData);
    return Stack(
      overflow: Overflow.visible,
      children: <Widget>[
        this.child,
        top > 0? Container(
          color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.9),
          height: top,
          width: width
        ):null,
        bottom > 0? Positioned(
          bottom: 0,
          child: Container(
            color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.9),
            height: bottom,
            width: width
          )
        ):null
      ].where((child) => child != null).toList()
    );
  }
}

class RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords> {
  final _suggestions = <WordPair>[];

  Widget buildSuggestions() {
    return ListView.separated(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      itemCount: 100,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        if(index >= _suggestions.length) {
          _suggestions.add(WordPair.random());
        }
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(
            _suggestions[index].asPascalCase,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)
          )
        );
      },
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return buildSuggestions();
  }
}

class RandomWords extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  RandomWordsState createState() => RandomWordsState();
}
```

Comment: Overflow is anti-pattern in Flutter. Don't. Instead just remove that SafeArea, this will allow the list to display content behind the top/bottom.

Comment: Without the SafeArea, the device status bar and menu bar will interfere with the content or the content will just disappear without a proper transition.
Or else I will need to put a shadow or a border to indicate the SafeArea, but this is a style preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for same, and finally used a simple solution without using `SafeArea()`:

Just apply a padding to ListView itself, which you can get using `MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.bottom`

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0).copyWith(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.bottom),
        itemCount: 2000,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Text("Item: $index");
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```